# Sharing google docs with write permission

Tags: php, google-drive-api, drive

Please help me!
I'm new to Google APIs

I have a front end page where users request for access to edit a Google doc. I'm using PHP for server side scripting.

I want to dynamically add edit access to user upon request. I explored and found that it's possible to do with Google Drive SDK. But I'm not getting how to do it.

I just tried to do like the PHP example at 
[PHP Sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing#examples)

I want to add single user each time and not in batch. Where exactly should I include the code?

Comment: You have try this sample or want some idea about start the scratch?

Comment: @Ajay Pandya I want to start from scratch. I dont know where to start with

Comment: What's the confusion in it's just simple flow with button and open popup in google developers example

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive apps can manage permission and sharing settings of files. Permission collection provides apps the ability to read, update and delete permission for users, Google groups, Google Apps domains, and the public.

Visit this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource-representations) for information on manipulating permission.